# How to go through each row with pandas apply() and lambda to clean sentence tokens?

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, nltk

My goal is to created a cleaned column of the tokenized sentence within the existing dataframe.
The dataset is a pandas dataframe looking like this:

| Index | Tokenized_sents |
| --- | --- |
| First | [Donald, Trump, just, couldn, t, wish, all, Am] |
| Second | [On, Friday, ,, it, was, revealed, that] |

```
dataset['cleaned_sents'] = dataset.apply(lambda row: [w for w in row["tokenized_sents"] if len(w)>2 and w.lower() not in stop_words], axis = 1)
```

My current output is the dataframe without that extra column.

Current outout:

```
    tokenized_sents  \
0  [Donald, Trump, just, couldn, t, wish, all, Am...
```

Wanted output:

```
  tokenized_sents  \
0  [Donald, Trump, just, couldn, wish, all...
```

Basically removing all the stopwords & short words

Comment: can you give an example of a concrete input and a concrete wanted output ?

Comment: edited it. Hope it is clearer now

Comment: Could you also give the code used to create your dataset, so that I can do a little bit of testing ?

Comment: Yes, done so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a sentence index

```
dataset['gid'] = range(1, dataset.shape[0] + 1)

       tokenized_sents  gid
0  [This, is, a, test]    1
1    [and, this, too!]    2
```

Then explode the dataframe

```
clean_df = dataset.explode('tokenized_sents')

  tokenized_sents  gid
0            This    1
0              is    1
0               a    1
0            test    1
1             and    2
1            this    2
1            too!    2
```

Do all the cleaning on this dataframe and use `gid` column to group them back. It will be the fastest way to go about doing it.

```
clean_df = clean_df[clean_df.tokenized_sents.str.len() >= 2]
.
.
.
```

To get it back,

```
clean_dataset = clean_df.groupby('gid').agg(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your code

```
dataset['new'] = dataset['tokenized_sents'].\
                   map(lambda x : [t for t in x if len(t)>2 and t not in stop] )
```